# is it possible to color specific area in drawcontour in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, opencv

I work in an image processing in python, I detect the patches using `cv2.minAreaRect` and draw a rotated rectangle, I achieved this.[image]

Now I want to fill the detected patch fully in white color, which means the area inside the `cv2.drawContour` in cyan color inside fully in white color(desire output has been done in ms-paint for reference) [image]
I want to achieve it in python, is it possible in OpenCV-python?

Comment: just set a negative thickness, e.g. `thickness=-1` in `drawContours`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have the contours saved in `cnts`. Then following snippet will fill the rotated rectangles with cyan color.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

for c in cnts:
    rotrect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rotrect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    cv2.drawContours(image, [box], 0, (255, 255, 0), -1) # as opencv stores in BGR format
```

Comment: it makes the whole image in cyan color

Comment: That can be caused by the outer contours which may cover the whole image. You need to sort the contours by area with ```cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)```. And then see if there are contours that covers the whole image. Usually the first 1 or 2 largest contours needs to be excluded from the above loop. As you didn't share the original image and your code, hence I have suggested one snippet. But you need to filter the contours as per your need.

Comment: Good to know it solved your issue. You may consider to accept the answer if it satisfies your need.

Answer (score 1):

@amras As per the above guidelines, I modified and post the code I used for all of your references

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


image=cv2.imread("CP150036_001bw.png",0)
im2=cv2.imread("CP150036_001.png")
# convert to RGB
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
# create a binary thresholded image
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# show it
plt.imshow(binary, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
# find the contours from the thresholded image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#print("contours:",contours)
# draw all contours
for c in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(c)>70000:
        continue


    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    #cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    ## BEGIN - draw rotated rectangle
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    im=cv2.drawContours(image,[box],0,(255,255,255),-1)
    #im3=cv2.drawContours(im2,[box], 0, (255, 0, 0), 2)

# show the image with the drawn contours
plt.imshow(image)
#plt.imshow(im3)
#cv2.imwrite("textDectBox.png",im3)
cv2.imwrite("detectImg.png",im)

plt.show()
```

[image]